# VueJS pass "watch" route to class component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I wanna use this to get whenever this route is clicked/called:

```html
watch: {
    $route (to, from) {
      console.log(to.params)
    }
  }
```

but in the format of a class component.
I saw in the documentation that now is using the @Watch but I couldn't understand how to transpose it.

Comment: What is a `class component` ? How is it different from `normal` components ? Are you talking about `mixin` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV https://class-component.vuejs.org/

Comment: Their documentation is quite clear about this - https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Watch